# Swap chars only given pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, swap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

If I have a pointer and I know the indexes of both the chars, how would I swap the chars(I didn't actually allocate an array)

i.e.

`char *str = "hello"` and I know and I wanted to swap the 'h' and 'o' which is index 0 and 4, and then return the pointer as well.

I'm used to doing the convention of

```
temp = array[i];
array[i] = array[j];
array[j] = temp;
```

Comment: This is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following declaration:

```
char *str = "hello";
```

Should be, to warn you about unsafe behaviors:

```
const char *str = "hello";
```

Because attempt to modify a string litteral is an undefined behavior according to C standard, you should rather use an array.

```
char str[] = "hello";
```

Then, swap the array's elements is easy and safe:

```
char tmp = str[0];
str[0] = str[4];
str[4] = tmp;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can't with pointer to a string literal. Literals are immutable. Stick with the way you've always done it.

Comment: So, If I was given a pointer to a string literal I would have to copy it into a char array?

Comment: Yeah, and then you can swap it. Did you try it? You should have gotten a segfault.

Comment: exactly I got a seg fault, that's why I was confused!

Comment: Yep, anyway some of the links in the comment box of your question should help ;) 
Trying to change the contents of a read only memory location is not good! :P

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = array[i];
array[i] = array[j];
array[j] = temp;
```

Comment: But I never said char[] s = {'h','e' ....}; How could I do it that way?

Comment: char* foo = "bar"; is equal to  char foo[] = {'b','a','r','\0' };

Comment: It's not equal. Different type, different behavior.

Comment: Sorry I must be new to c then, could you explain the difference between the two char pointers for me?

Answer (score 0):

Some operating systems / compilers allow you to do modify string literals, mainly AIX 5.1.

If modify the string literal in your code, it makes it a pain to have your code cross platform as you have to rewrite your code to compile for Linux.